# Is there a way to schedule events on ios programmatically?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, xcode

I am creating a reminder application that will allow users to remind user to send sms or email. at any day in the future.For example a user wants that the app reminds it for the birthday of a friend in the future.So the app would remind the user that day and show the user some prestored text to send as sms or email.
Can you suggest a good way to schedule these reminders for my app?
One of the ways I came up with was to schedule local notifications each day but I don't know if that would work.